# Limit of $x^{-4}\left(1-e^{x^2/2}\cos \left(x\right)\right)$ when $x\to0$, using expansions of $\exp$ and $\cos$

Tags: taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

Studying for my exam I came across this problem:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-e^{x^2/2}\cdot\cos x}{x^4}\right) \\$$

In the answer they solve it by first expanding, when $t\to0$,
$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}++O\left(t^3\right)$$ and when $x\to0$,
$$e^{x^2/2}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
and
$$\cos \left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Then we're supposed plug it in to the numerator to get

$$1-e^{x^2/2}\cos \left(x\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{24}\right)x^4+O\left(x^6\right)=\frac{1}{12}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$

and then divide by $x^4$ to be left with just $\frac{1}{12}$.

I don't understand what happens after we plug everything in to the numerator, however. There seems to have been some steps of simplifying as I can see the resemblance between the left-hand side and the right. Some explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that your result is right?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It should be. I'm following some proposed solutions.

Comment: the proposed Solutions are wrong, there is no Limit, it is $-\infty$

Comment: no it is another thing

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I had one pair of parentheses too many. Does it make a difference?

Comment: yes it does make an importend difference

Comment: your result $\frac{1}{12}$ is right

Comment: What happened when you tried to expand $$e^{x^2/2}\cos \left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)\right)$$ and to collect all the terms of order $1$, $x^2$, $x^4$ and $O(x^6)$ respectively?

Comment: @Did I ended up with something that still had terms other than $x^4$ and $O(x^6)$ in it. Perhaps I made some mistakes?

Comment: Unless you show the details of what you tried, this will not be very fruitful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the taylor series, they have found that:

$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right), x\rightarrow 0$

$\cos \left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right), x\rightarrow 0 \\$

Note that we can ignore the terms of $x$ which are higher powers when computing the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, because they go to $0$ 'faster' than lower powers of $x$. We refer to them as 'dominant' terms.

So, we can consider the powers of $x$ up to $x^{4}$ and see what we get.

$e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\cos x = (1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{8} + O(x^{6}))(1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{24} + O(x^{6}))$

We want to only consider the terms up to and including $x^{4}$

$e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\cos x = 1 -\frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{24} +\frac{x^{2}}{2} -\frac{x^{4}}{4} +\frac{x^{4}}{8} + O(x^{6})$

Then we get $1- e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\cos x =1 -(1 -\frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{24} +\frac{x^{2}}{2} -\frac{x^{4}}{4} +\frac{x^{4}}{8})$

$1- e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\cos x = \frac{x^{4}}{12} + O(x^{6})$

Again, note that we don't care what the coefficient of the terms after $x^{4}$ are, since they will all tend to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ much faster than $x^{4}$ will.

When you factorise the numerator you get the following:

$\frac{x^{4}(\frac{1}{12} + \frac{O(x^{6})}{x^{4}})}{x^{4}}$

Now by considering what happens when $x \rightarrow 0$, you can see that all terms after $\frac{1}{12}$ go to $0$, therefore the limit is $\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: How does factorising the numerator get to that? Could you show me more specific?

Comment: do you understand how they arrive at this line? $1-e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\cos \left(x\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{24}\right)x^4+O\left(x^6\right)=\frac{1}{12}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$,

Comment: No, that's where I get confused.

Comment: Okay one moment then

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you very much!